# MySQL user-defined function for getting the modal value of a column?

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions, mode

For example:

```
SELECT MODE(field) FROM table
```

In another mode, what **user-defined function** can I use to get the most common value of a column?

I know I can do something like:

```
SELECT field, COUNT(*) as total FROM table GROUP BY field ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1
```

But I have to query other data in the same MySQL statement too, so I have to use a user-defined function.

Thank you.

Comment: What other data are you trying to get ? i think your going to need to issue multiple queries here

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to [MySQL's documentation on aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html).  It looks like they don't have anything for "mode", so I would say that your second query is probably your best shot.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support user-defined aggregate functions ([PostgreSQL does](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xaggr.html), for what it's worth).  You can't use a UDF to do what you want in MySQL.

You can do it for example by putting the mode-computation in a derived table subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT field AS mode, COUNT(*) as total FROM table 
      GROUP BY field ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1) AS m
JOIN table t ON m.mode = t.field;
```